# User Defined Slice function in python script

Tags: python-3.x

A function 'drop' that takes a list and a number 'n', returning the list without the first 'n' elements from the list passed.

```
 List<int> drop(List<int> list, int n);
```

eg:

```
drop([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2) == [3, 4, 5]
```

I know python have predefined method.

```
>>> spam=[1,2,3,4,5] #spam List
>>> spam[2:] #spam Slicing
[3,4,5]
```

However need above list slice method in user defined way.

Comment: So what's wrong with `n = 2`, `spam[n:]`? You don't have to use integer literals in a slice, you can use any expression..

Comment: if i use spam=['a','b','c','d','e'] and spam[3:] then [d,e]. but i need to write a script in user defined way. did n't  use any predefined methods or function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
def drop(list, slice):
    return list[slice:]
```

...

```
>>> nums = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> drop(nums, 2)
[3, 4, 5]
```

...

```
>>> letters = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> drop(letters, 3)
['d', 'e']
```